# Create a pandas DataFrame from a list of dictionaries with dictionary keys set as row labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a single key-vaue pair. I want to convert this list into a pandas DataFrame that has a single column "time" containing the values in the rows from each dictionary with the label for each row being the key from the corresponding dictionary item.

As an example, I will show only the first two elements from the list:

```
list_example = [{'companies_info_5000_5100': 121.20147228240967},\
 {'companies_info_5100_5200': 116.49221062660217}]
```

from this `list_example` I want to create a DataFrame like this one:

|  | time |
| --- | --- |
| companies_info_5000_5100 | 121.201472 |
| companies_info_5100_5200 | 116.492211 |

I have searched for possible solutions and came up with my own solution which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = []
for d in list_example:
    d_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index", columns=["time"])
    df_list.append(d_df)
df = pd.concat(df_list,axis= 0)
```

With this code I get what I want, **BUT** I am sure there must be some function that does this more efficiently without the for loop. For example, if I run `df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)`, then it creates a DataFrame but dictionary keys are used as columns and I get NaNs in the DataFrame. I am sure there must be some modification of this function that tells pandas to use keys as row labels. Iam looking for this simpler and more elegant  and Pythonic solution.

As far as I searched here I couldnot find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this<sup>1</sup>

```
# build a nested dict from list_example and build df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: {'time': v} for d in list_example for k,v in d.items()}, orient='index')
print(df)
                                time
companies_info_5000_5100  121.201472
companies_info_5100_5200  116.492211
```

<sup>1</sup>: This method doesn't build a dataframe for each row. Reformatting the dictionary will be much more efficient than the method in the OP. For example, for a dataframe with 10000 rows, this solution takes 24.3 ms while the one in the OP take 4s (this one is 164 times faster).

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df = (pd.concat(map(pd.Series, list_example))
        .to_frame('time')
      )
```

Output:

```
                                time
companies_info_5000_5100  121.201472
companies_info_5100_5200  116.492211
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions is to:

- create a *Series* from each dictionary,
- concatenate them (so far the result is still a *Series*),
- convert it to a *DataFrame*, setting the name of the (only) column.

The code to do it is:

```
result = pd.concat([ pd.Series(d.values(), index=d.keys())
    for d in list_example ]).to_frame('time')
```

For your sample data I got:

```
                                time
companies_info_5000_5100  121.201472
companies_info_5100_5200  116.492211
```

Comment: That's more or less what I already suggested (but with a list comprehension instead of `map`) ;)

Comment: It turns out that we concurrently got almost the same idea. For some time new answers are not visible to the others, so I initially didn't see your solution. I noticed it only after I submitted my solution.

Comment: @mozway Your suggestion turns out to be much much faster. In particular for a list of dicts of length 1000000, you suggestion needs 21 secs while the this one needs 183 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

### Pandas approach

```
pd.DataFrame(list_example).stack().droplevel(0).to_frame('time')
```

---

```
                                time
companies_info_5000_5100  121.201472
companies_info_5100_5200  116.492211
```

Comment: The drawback is that it creates a large intermediate structure with many NaN if the list is large (O(n^2) size)

Comment: This by far is the worst approach. With a list of 1000000 dicts it crashes due to insufficient RAM of 13 Gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

This question recieved 4 helpful answers.

All of them work and do the job **although** according stackoverflow rules, only one accepted answer is allowed. So, I decided to check their speed and accept the most efficient (fastest) answer.

For this, I created an artificial list of dicts of length 100,000:

```
check_length = 100000

list_example = []

for i in range(check_length):
    list_example.append({f"companies_info_{i}": i})
```

Then, I defined 4 methods

| Method name | Author |
| --- | --- |
| **Method 1** | Me |
| **Method 2** | My own suggested solution described in the question |
| **Method 3** | @mozway |
| **Method 4** | @cottontail |
| **Method 5** | @Valdi_Bo |

I discarded the last method called **Pandas approach** suggested by @Shubham Sharma because even 12 GBs of RAM are not enough for that. So, clearly it is the worst way.

The results of 100 iterations of the list with 100000 dictionaries are the following:

| Method name | Author | Results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Method 1** | Me | 58.829195756912235, 95% CI (58.436393856257794, 59.221997657566675) |
| **Method 2** | My own suggested solution described in the question | 28.41278486251831, 95% CI (28.330043057325845, 28.495526667710777) |
| **Method 3** | @mozway | 17.587587616443635, 95% CI (17.526133899890418, 17.649041332996852) |
| **Method 4** | @cottontail | 0.20350171089172364, 95% CI (0.19587073491102097, 0.2111326868724263) |
| **Method 5** | @Valdi_Bo | 15.767115621566772, 95% CI (15.721122343444568, 15.813108899688975) |

P.S. If anyone is intrested in my code for checking the speed of each cases it is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import math


# Method 1

def get_frame_method_1(l):

    list_example_d = {"time": l}

    df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=list_example_d, orient="columns")

    index_list = []

    for count, d in enumerate(df_1.time):
        index_list.extend(list(d.keys()))
        df_1.time[count]= list(d.values())[0]

    df_1.index= index_list

    return df_1


# Method 2

def get_frame_method_2(l):

    df_list = []

    for d in l:
        d_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient="index", columns=["time"])
        df_list.append(d_df)

    df_2 = pd.concat(df_list, axis= 0)

    return df_2


# Method 3

def get_frame_method_3(l):

    df_3 = (pd.concat(map(pd.Series, l))
            .to_frame('time')
        )
    
    return df_3


# Method 4

def get_frame_method_4(l):

    # build a nested dict from list_example and build df
    df_4 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: {'time': v} for d in l for k,v in d.items()}, orient='index')

    return df_4


# Method 5

def get_frame_method_5(l):

    df_5 = pd.concat([ pd.Series(d.values(), index=d.keys())
        for d in l ]).to_frame('time')
    
    return df_4


check_length = 100000

list_example = []

for i in range(check_length):
    list_example.append({f"companies_info_{i}": i})


total_time_1_d = {}

for i in range(100):
    t_0 = time.time()
    df_1 = get_frame_method_1(list_example)
    t_1 = time.time()
    df_2 = get_frame_method_2(list_example)
    t_2 = time.time()
    df_3 = get_frame_method_3(list_example)
    t_3 = time.time()
    df_4 = get_frame_method_4(list_example)
    t_4 = time.time()
    df_5= get_frame_method_5(list_example)
    t_5 = time.time()
    total_time_1_d[f"{i}"] = {"Method 1": (t_1-t_0), "Method 2": (t_2-t_1), "Method 3": (t_3-t_2), "Method 4": (t_4-t_3), "Method 5": (t_5-t_4)}
    print(i)


total_time_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data= total_time_1_d, orient="index")


for i in range(5):
    print(f"Method {i+1}: Mean - {total_time_df.describe().iloc[1, i]}, 95% CI ({total_time_df.describe().iloc[1, i]-1.96*(total_time_df.describe().iloc[2, i])/math.sqrt((total_time_df.describe().iloc[0, i]))}, {total_time_df.describe().iloc[1, i]+1.96*(total_time_df.describe().iloc[2, i])/math.sqrt((total_time_df.describe().iloc[0, i]))})")
```